# How to replace settings in WordPress plugin from a theme

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, hooks, customization

I created an array with some default settings in a plugin, and want to allow it to be replaced from functions.php in a theme without using stored data (eg. add_option). I want this to be just a hook with new values.

example array inside plugin:

```
$default_settings = array(
   'key_one' => 0,
   'key_two' => 1
);
```

I need to allow this to be changed from a theme's functions.php, so a developer can add something like this:

```
add_filter('the_hook','my_function');
function my_function(){
  $default_settings = array(
       'key_one' => 1, //changed value
       'key_two' => 1
  );
}
```

If a developer makes this call, then I want the new values replacing the old array inside the plugin. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already pretty close. Extending your example:

In your plugin put this:

```
$default_settings = array(
   'key_one' => 0,
   'key_two' => 1
);
$settings = apply_filters( 'example_filter', $default_settings);
```

Then a theme can change it like this:

```
add_filter('example_filter','my_function');
function my_function($settings){
   $settings['key_one'] = 1;
   return $settings;
}
```

Comment: Just make sure to call `apply_filters` at an appropriate time.

Comment: thanks for this, I do believe I have to call at a time like still_learning mentions, I can't see the new results. I added print_r($settings); right after $settings = apply_filters.... but I'm still getting the old values. Example: Array ( [key_one] => 0 [key_two] => 1 )

Comment: sorry, just figured out what i had to do, thanks. I added this into a new function, then an action with init. Works now.